# Call static method from a string name in PHP

Tags: php, yii, static-methods

I need to call a static method of a class, but I only have a classname, not an instance of it. I am doing it this way.

```
$class = new "ModelName";
$items = $class::model()->findAll();
```

It works on my computer, but when I move to the server, it throws an `unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`, so I think it actually expects model to be a variable instead of a method.

PS: If it helps, it's Yii framework, so if there's another way to call the find() functions, it's ok to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because your server runs a version of PHP earlier than 5.3.0, in which this syntax is not supported.

From the documentation on the [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a
>   variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent
>   and static).

In any case, you can always use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$class = "ModelName"; // the "new" in your example was a typo, right?
$items = call_user_func(array($class, 'model'))->findAll();
```

Comment: Definitely not as dirty as mine, once I can, I'll accept your answer. By the way, it wasn't. In fact, it magically worked offline. And thanks to your clarification, I know why. Thanks!