# Use an object property as a class name to call a method statically?

Tags: php, oop

So I've got an object of class `Son`:

```
class Son extends Father {
    $_modelName = 'House';
}
```

And another of class `Daughter`:

```
class Daughter extends Father {
    $_modelName = 'Museum';
}
```

And I want their parent class `Father` to be able to call static methods on their respective objects.

```
class Father {
    public function foo() {
        $className = $this->_modelName;
        return $className::bar();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Basically, I want to be able to call the `foo()` method, and have that call the `bar()` method, from the corresponding model class, avoiding the use of an extra variable (`$className`)? I tried `{$this->_modelName}::bar()` without success.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410932/call-static-method-from-a-string-name-in-php if you haven't, it might simply be a PHP version issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be difficult to achieve from a model name as a string, but maybe you can consider things just a bit differently?

since php 5, we can assign objects to a variable [without moving the entire object around](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

this means that when you assign the `modelName` to your `Son` or `Daughter` class, you can as easily assign it...

... a whole class!

imagine this:

```
class Father {
  private $model;
  public function __construct($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
  }
  public function foo() {
    return $this->model->bar();
  }
}
class Son extends Father {
}
class Daughter extends Father {
}
```

this assumes that you construct both `Son` and `Daughter` classes with this model object. The function is not static because we need a constructor to assign the model to a property.

#### But you could also consider passing the model to the `foo()` function:

```
public function foo($model) {
  return $model->bar();
}
```

that, in regard to the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) principle, allows you to very easily implement your `foo()` function, and is much better then depending on somewhat complex design problems with inheritance and such.

it **frees** you from the dependency of this function since you can pass any `$model` object to the foo method.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this:

```
<?php

    class Son extends Father {
        protected $_modelName = 'House';
    }

    class Daughter extends Father {
       protected $_modelName = 'Museum';
    }

    class Father {
        protected $_modelName = 'Father';
        public function getModelName() {
            return $this->_modelName;
        }
    }

    $father =  new Father();
    $son = new Son;
    $daughter = new Daughter();

     echo $father->getModelName();
     echo $son->getModelName();
     echo $daughter->getModelName();
?>
```

Comment: It's not quite that what I want to do, please check the edit.